# Gatsby - How to set ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT to true

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, gatsby

To enable /__refresh end point, I have to set ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT to true, but I don't know how to add environment variables to gatsby. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the root of your project, you'll want to create a `.env.development` file if you don't have one already and add the following:

```
ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true
```

You will also want to add that file to your project's `.gitignore`, it's good practice to not commit `.env` files to source control. Gatsby outlines how to use environment variables [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#example).

Comment: I've created a `.env.development` file with `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true` and started Gatsby with `gatsby develop`. Unfortunately Gatsby is not picking up the variable.

Comment: You can test `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true gatsby develop`

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this thread, you need to send a `post` request to http://localhost:8000 to refresh. More information [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10328).

Comment: somehow i missed this as an environment variable and thought it was a gatsby-config flag at first, so thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just like chrisotto6's answer, you need to create a file `.env.development` in the root directory and paste the following in it:

```
ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true
```

The important thing after that is place the following code to the top of `gatsby-config.js` so that Gatsby can read the env var:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Refer [document](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/).

Answer (score 1):

use this in terminal, it work for me:

curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh

if not:
change like this:

require("dotenv").config({
path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});